# Download xml file from URL to server for cron

Tags: php, url, download, cron

I’ve a problem, probably not so difficult most of you…
Please help me

There is https://fakesite.com/example  where is xml file. When I give this URL to explorer, asks what I would like do this file, where I want save etc.

I need a small php script to my server, which is enable to download this xml file and save into my predefined server folder. If the file (filename) already exist in my root folder, overwrite them.  The file name not important, would be original or anything with extension xml. This php script should have run, when cron calls.

Any help would be appreciated….

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are asking three questions at once. Please only ask one question per question. And please use the search first, as you already noticed, this is nothing special, so you should be able to obtain that information on your own by doing an internet search.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to download file contents.
2. Create an output file name ie. using date ( `date('Ymd-His')` ) or a random string ( `md5(date('now'))` )
3. Save data to the file using [file_put_contents](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).